# How do get the spark job's lineage/dag information after the jobs has finished from logs ? Not from the web UI

Tags: apache-spark

I want get the lineage information of the spark job in a way that spark show's the lineage when we use **toDebugString**().

I don't want to use the web ui to see the dag , but I would want the same information may in a log file etc.

I am querying spark rest api (http://:18080/api/v1) to get some metrics , I would want to get hold of the spark job's lineage information but there is no api for it.

Does spark log the linage information some where ?

Is there a way to get hold of the linage information of a completed or failed job in some what like **toDebugString()** kind of format , apart from using the web ui ?

I am using spark java api.